# Excel Writer adds only latest sheet | Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I'm working in Jupyter Labs and I'm creating new excel initially and then trying to add new sheets to same excel but I'm only getting one sheet written to excel that is latest sheet that I'm adding.

In first block I'm creating like this:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('EXPLANATORYDATA.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer: 
    df1.sort_values(['Start','LocationPick'],ascending=[True,True]).to_excel(writer,sheet_name='CRITICALBREAKS')
```

In second block I'm trying to append:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('EXPLANATORYDATA.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter',mode=a) as writer: 
    df2.sort_values(['Start','LocationPick'],ascending=[True,True]).to_excel(writer,sheet_name='ELIGIBLETRIPS')
```

But I'm only getting ELIGIBLETRIPS named sheet.

Any possible solution or is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just guessing, but did you try not to force `xlsxwriter` and instead user `openpyxl` as engine?

Comment: But this says you can add sheets https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html
Am I missing something ?

Comment: I'll try without mentioning engine if that yields different results but engine is selected as per extension so I guess this might be default one too

Comment: It  looks like the file is being closed by the `with` context managers and/or the fact that you are calling `pd.ExcelWriter()` repeatedly. Try creating the `writer` once and then reusing it in the `to_excel()` calls.

Comment: @jmcnamara I tried           
df2.sort_values(['Start','LocationPick'],ascending=[True,True]).to_excel(writer,sheet_name='ELIGIBLETRIPS')

But this time I only got CRITICALBREAKS named sheet and not ELIGIBLETRIPS named sheet :(

Comment: And you dropped both `with()` statements and only called `pd.ExcelWriter()` once? For reference here is a panda/xlsxwriter example that adds multiple worksheets: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html#ex-pandas-multiple

Comment: I just dropped with statement in consecutive calls, in first call I'm using with statement.
I'll check example too if that helps :)
PS: I've deleted excel file too before re running program